# Fabric.js : How to save canvas image without background image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm a new for fabric canvas. I wanna save canvas as png file without background image. I try save canvas following my code below, it's saved background image.

**In my code**

```
<template>
    <canvas
        ref="can"
        id="canvas"
        width="500"
        height="500"
    ></canvas>
    <button @click="saveImage">save</button>
</template>
<script>
    import { fabric } from 'fabric'
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
     mounted() {
         const ref = this.$refs.can
         canvas = new fabric.Canvas(ref)
         canvas.setBackgroundImage("https://www.test.com/background.png", canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
         fabric.Image.fromURL("https://www.test.com/pattern.png, function (patternImage) {
             patternImage.set({
                 selectable: true,
                 lockScalingFlip: true,
                 editable: true,
             })
             patternImage.scaleToHeight(120)
             patternImage.scaleToWidth(120)
             canvas.add(patternImage)
         }) 
     },
     method: {
         saveImage() {
             let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                 format: 'png',
                 multiplier: 2,
              })
              let file = new File([dataURL], "canvas.png")      
              saveAs(dataURL, "pretty image.png")
         }
     }
</script>
```

I try coding like this but it error `canvas._objects.toDataURL({...}) is not a function` I coding like this because I will select only objects in canvas without background image

```
saveImage() {
    let dataURL = canvas._objects.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        multiplier: 2,
    })
    let file = new File([dataURL], "canvas.png")      
    saveAs(dataURL, "pretty image.png")
}
```

How to fix this problem. Thank

Comment: What is `_objects` actually? `toDataURL` can just be called on a canvas instance, this is why you get an **is not a function** error.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the background image before saving the canvas, then display it after saving it, and nobody will notice.

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(null);
canvas.renderAll();

// ... save your canvas here

canvas.setBackgroundImage(myBgImage)
canvas.renderAll()
```

the download won't work here because of the iframe restriction, here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxe7jLya/)

```js
const c = document.querySelector('canvas');
let bg;

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c);
canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);

var bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.onload = function (img) {
    bg = new fabric.Image(bgImg, {
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
    });
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg)
        canvas.renderAll()
};
bgImg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg"; 

var object1 = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: '#1565c0',
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
});

var object2 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 15,
    fill: '#990000',
    left: 100,
    top: 100
});

canvas.add(object1, object2); 
canvas.renderAll();

const exportbutton = document.querySelector('button');
exportbutton.onclick = () => {

    canvas.setBackgroundImage(null);
    canvas.renderAll();

    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        multiplier: 2,
    })

    downloadDataUrl(dataURL);   

    canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg)
    canvas.renderAll()
    
}

async function downloadDataUrl(dataURL) {
    const blob = await fetch(dataURL).then(r => r.blob());
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = "my_image.png"
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button>Export</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```